# How to get tic tac toe python code to tell the user that the place they choose is invalid and that they need to choose a space between 1 to 9

Tags: python

```
theBoard = {'7': ' ' , '8': ' ' , '9': ' ' ,
           '4': ' ' , '5': ' ' , '6': ' ' ,
           '1': ' ' , '2': ' ' , '3': ' ' }
 
board_keys = []
 
for key in theBoard:
   board_keys.append(key)
```

#this will print the updated board after every move in the game.

```
def printBoard(board):
    print(board['7'] + ' |' + board['8'] + ' |' + board['9'])
    print('--+--+--')
    print(board['4'] + ' |' + board['5'] + ' |' + board['6'])
    print('--+--+--')
    print(board['1'] + ' |' + board['2'] + ' |' + board['3'])
```

#this will tell the user when they type an invalid input to choose an input specifically between 1 to 9.
def game():

```
   turn = 'X'
   count = 0
   # this prints that its x's or o's turn now and asks where they want to move to.
   for i in range(0, 10 ):
       printBoard(theBoard)
       print("It's your turn " + turn + "  please choose a number between 1 and 9")
       move = input()       
       
       if theBoard [move] == ' ':
           theBoard [move] = turn
           count += 1
       
       else:
           print("this place is already filled " + turn + " where do you want to move to?")
       
           # Now we will check if player X or O has won,for every move after 5 moves. 
       if count >= 5:
           if theBoard['7'] == theBoard['8'] == theBoard['9'] != ' ': # this goes across the top
               printBoard(theBoard)
               print("\ngame ooover\n")               
               print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")               
               break
           elif theBoard['4'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['6'] != ' ': # this goes across the middle
               printBoard(theBoard)
               print("\ngame oooover\n")               
               print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
               break
           elif theBoard['1'] == theBoard['2'] == theBoard['3'] != ' ': # this goes across the bottom
               printBoard(theBoard)
               print("\ngame ooover\n")               
               print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
               break
           elif theBoard['1'] == theBoard['4'] == theBoard['7'] != ' ': # this goes down the left side
               printBoard(theBoard)
               print("\ngame ooover\n")               
               print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
               break
           elif theBoard['2'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['8'] != ' ': # this goes down the middle
               printBoard(theBoard)
               print("\ngame ooover\n")               
               print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
               break
           elif theBoard['3'] == theBoard['6'] == theBoard['9'] != ' ': # this goes down the right side
               printBoard(theBoard)
               print("\ngame oooover\n")               
               print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
               break
           elif theBoard['7'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['3'] != ' ': # this goes diagonal
               printBoard(theBoard)
               print("\ngame ooover\n")               
               print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
               break
           elif theBoard['1'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['9'] != ' ': # this goes diagonal
               printBoard(theBoard)
               print("\ngame ooover\n")               
               print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
               break
             # \n means create a new line asking the question. 
             # if neither X nor O wins and the board is full, we'll declare the result as 'tie' because well its a tie.
       if count == 9:
           print("\nGame Over\n")               
           print("It's a Tie!!")
           break 
 
        # now we have to change the player after every move so that each player gets a turn.
       if turn =='X':
           turn = 'O'
       else:
           turn = 'X'
```

## now we will ask if player wants to restart the game or not, if yes then the game will restart and print the board again, if not then the game will end there.

```
   restart = input("would you like to play Again?(yup/nah)")
   if restart == "yup" or restart == "Yup": 
       for key in board_keys:
           theBoard[key] = " "
 
       game()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   game()
```

this is all of my code. Whenever I put a number that is not between 1 to 9 it breaks and says this "

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 123, in <module>
    game()
  File "main.py", line 51, in game
    if theBoard [move] == ' ':
KeyError: '0'"
```

I have tried many ways but I can't seem to find the right way to solve the problem.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem.  This includes fully-defined variables and the *full* error message.

Comment: That means post all your code(not some of it) and your error message too.

Comment: Why don't you just check that `move` is in `range(1,9)` before you use it?

Comment: please post more code

Comment: @ppwater - it does not mean "post all of your code". It means "post the minimal code necessary to reproduce the error."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `move` variable is an int variable type. It may be a string and needs to be converted to an int so that you can use it as an index for theBoard.

Here's an example of a way you can do it. Create the function `getMove()`

```
def getMove():
  got_move = False

  while got_move is False:
    move = input("Enter a number 1-9: ")

    if move.isdigit():
      move = int(move)

      if move <= 9 and move >= 1:
        got_move = True
      else:
        print("\n*** move is out of bounds. Numbers 1-9 only ***\n")
    else:
      print("\n*** Invalid input. Numbers 1-9 only ***\n")

  return move
```

Then change your code where you are assigning 'move' like this:

```
move = getMove()
```

Comment: Can you add an example, then it will be more helpful

Comment: Okay, Much better!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
theBoard = {'7': ' ' , '8': ' ' , '9': ' ' ,
           '4': ' ' , '5': ' ' , '6': ' ' ,
           '1': ' ' , '2': ' ' , '3': ' ' }
 
board_keys = []
 
for key in theBoard:
   board_keys.append(key)
#this will print the updated board after every move in the game.

def printBoard(board):
    print(board['7'] + ' |' + board['8'] + ' |' + board['9'])
    print('--+--+--')
    print(board['4'] + ' |' + board['5'] + ' |' + board['6'])
    print('--+--+--')
    print(board['1'] + ' |' + board['2'] + ' |' + board['3'])
#this will tell the user when they type an invalid input to choose an input specifically between 1 to 9. def game():

turn = 'X'   
count = 0
# this prints that its x's or o's turn now and asks where they want to move to.
for i in range(0, 10 ):
    printBoard(theBoard)
    print("It's your turn " + turn + "  please choose a number between 1 and 9")
    move = input()       
    try: #here
        if str(theBoard[move]) == ' ':
            theBoard[move] = turn
            count += 1
    except KeyError: #here
        pass #here
        
       
    else:
        print("this place is already filled " + turn + " where do you want to move to?")
       
           # Now we will check if player X or O has won,for every move after 5 moves. 
    if count >= 5:
        if theBoard['7'] == theBoard['8'] == theBoard['9'] != ' ': # this goes across the top
            printBoard(theBoard)
            print("\ngame ooover\n")               
            print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")               
            break
        elif theBoard['4'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['6'] != ' ': # this goes across the middle
            printBoard(theBoard)
            print("\ngame oooover\n")               
            print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
            break
        elif theBoard['1'] == theBoard['2'] == theBoard['3'] != ' ': # this goes across the bottom
            printBoard(theBoard)
            print("\ngame ooover\n")               
            print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
            break
        elif theBoard['1'] == theBoard['4'] == theBoard['7'] != ' ': # this goes down the left side
            printBoard(theBoard)
            print("\ngame ooover\n")               
            print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
            break
        elif theBoard['2'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['8'] != ' ': # this goes down the middle
            printBoard(theBoard)
            print("\ngame ooover\n")               
            print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
            break
        elif theBoard['3'] == theBoard['6'] == theBoard['9'] != ' ': # this goes down the right side
            printBoard(theBoard)
            print("\ngame oooover\n")               
            print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
            break
        elif theBoard['7'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['3'] != ' ': # this goes diagonal
            printBoard(theBoard)
            print("\ngame ooover\n")               
            print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
            break
        elif theBoard['1'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['9'] != ' ': # this goes diagonal
            printBoard(theBoard)
            print("\ngame ooover\n")               
            print(" yipee " +turn + " won! yoohooo")
            break
        # \n means create a new line asking the question. 
             # if neither X nor O wins and the board is full, we'll declare the result as 'tie' because well its a tie.
        if count == 9:
            print("\nGame Over\n")               
            print("It's a Tie!!")
            break 
 
        # now we have to change the player after every move so that each player gets a turn.
        if turn =='X':
            turn = 'O'
        else:
            turn = 'X'       
  
# now we will ask if player wants to restart the game or not, if yes then the game will restart and print the board again, if not then the game will end there.
restart = input("would you like to play Again?(yup/nah)")
if restart == "yup" or restart == "Yup": 
    for key in board_keys:
       theBoard[key] = " "
 
       game()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   game()
```

I added [`try: except: pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to the error part, so if the input is not a number, It will just repeat the question again.